# Reasons why except block  in "try..except" is bypassed

Tags: delphi, debugging, try-except

I am writing some code against a 3rd party component with no source code. (don't comment on this :) ), something happens when calling a method on that component and even if i put it in a try except block the except block is bypassed.

Am i doing something wrong?

What can be the reason?

```
begin
  try
    3rdPartyComponentWithNoSourceCode.MethodOne; [A]
    SomeOtherCode;
  except
    HandleException; [A']
  end;
end; [B]
```

debugging step by step brings me from [A] to [B], without stopping on [A'].

Why?

Comment: So *neither* `SomeOtherCode` *nor* `HandleException` is executed?

Comment: Does the application proceed normally after hitting `[B]`?

Comment: Does your `except` section include an `on exception do...` clause? If not, add `on Exception do` before `HandleException;` and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Because there hasn't been an exception ;)  What does SomeOtherCode do ? Could it have been optimized out ?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes, after pressin F8 it jumps directly on [B]. I never saw that but I forgot to say that the 3rd party component is an ActiveX component. May be is this the reason? (it is a wrapper of an ActiveX)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger doesn't jump to exception handlers well when you're stepping through your code. Put a breakpoint on HandleException instead, and it will stop there (if there is an exception in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

A reason for not reaching `HandleException` could be that any exception raised within `MethodOne` might be eaten or handled by `MethodOne` itself.

But that's propably not the case, because:

> something happens

Could you expand on the *something*?